# Printing document with custom HTML tags

Tags: jquery

I need to print a document which will be formatted differently in print. I can use @media for print and specify some styles that I want in print to be formatted differently than on the screen.

However, the screen version of the document is using some custom HTML attributes, that prevent parts of the document rendered in print. In order for me to be able to print the entire document I need to use something like jQuery's .removeAttr('customAttr').

For example I have the following in my CSS

```
@media screen {
    .myClass h1 {
        display:none
    }
}
```

So I tried using something like

```
if( $('.myClass h1').css('display') != 'none') {
    $('.anotherClass').removeAttr('customAttr');
}
```

Unfortunately it did not work. So, how do I make my jQuery execute only in print version?

Comment: Having a data-attribute makes the element not render in print?

Comment: I would suggest creating another document for print.

Comment: Yes, it's based on Foundation framework and the data attribute is used to create tabs.

Answer (score 2):

*I think* there is no way to do that. A solution is to put a button that calls a function and do stuff before call `window.print()` or create a new window, but if the user goes to File, Print it is no way to remove attributes. I think, the best solution, is putting a print button somewhere.

Comment: I thought of a button, but the moment I click it it removes attribute for on screen version as well...

Comment: Yes, I think the best choice for your issue is creating a new window. You could also make a copy of affected elements by the question is when you should restore them. Anyway it is a hard issue to resolve :)

Comment: I found **[this mozilla mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing)**. I'm not sure about compatibility with other browsers but maybe it is a point to start solving your issue